# Aggregation using $sample

Tags: mongodb, random, aggregation-framework, sample

With an aggregation using `{ $sample: { size: 3 } }`, I'll get `3` random documents returned.

How can I use a percentage of all documents instead?

Something that'd look like `{ $sample: { size: 50% } }`?

Comment: Here we like to fix code issue. Please try something to improve your change to get help from us. Also reading [ask] might be worthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it, as expression to `$sample` should be a positive number.

If you still needed to use `$sample` you can try to get the total count of documents in a collection, get number half of it & then run `$sample` :

1) Count no.of documents in a collection (**mongo Shell**) :

```
var totalDocumentsCount = db.yourCollectionName.count()/2

print(totalDocumentsCount) // Replace it with console.log() in code
```

2) `$sample` for random documents :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{$sample : {size : totalDocumentsCount}}])
```

**Note :**

If you wanted to get half of the documents from the collection (Which is 50% of documents) then `$sample` might not be a good option - it can become an inefficient query. Also result of `$sample` can have duplicate documents being returned (So really you might not get unique 50% of documents).  Try to read more about it here : [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/index.html)

Comment: I got you will read $sample thanks. Main question.  --> I have table with lot of data, my goal is to create filter which will have input  of % data

Comment: @Babken : So do you want to get random % unique documents of first few % or last few %, or just random % of documents ?

Comment: just random % documents, I want to know are there ready function in mongo? or I need to do something custom.

Comment: @Babken : As far as I know there is nothing that takes in `%` , you can use `$limit` to get certain number of documents but that too need a number, but I would suggest to go with `$sample` cause it would give you random documents, but you need to do as suggested above :-)

Comment: `{ $unwind: '$items' },
{ $match: { 'items.polNum': { $exists: true } } },
{
     $project: {
             _id: '$items._id', polNum: '$items.polNum',
                  polProdCode: '$items.polProdCode', **myVariable**: '$countSomething', (..etc...)
     }
},
{ $sample: { size: **'$<myVariable>'** } },`
okay then I need to put example "myVariable" as integer number which I get from previous query of aggregation

Comment: @Babken : Yes correct, this is easy with two queries, even we can do this in one query but it would be hefty, that too putting that hefty query at the end of this query wouldn't be good.

Comment: Yes, but **myVariable** in this case is external variable, I need value which I get as result from previous step. So how use variable instead of integer number in this expression -> 
` { $sample: { size : < **myVariable** > } } `

Comment: @Babken : How does this query run on mongoDB, if it's running from code, then just before to hit database you pass the number as an input to query, then from mongoose to DB to mongoose(Node.js)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for this solution in PHP just use this as required in your aggregate at the end ( i.e before projection ) and avoid using limit and sort

```
[
  '$sample' => [                                                                                                     
                 'size' => 30                                                                                                
               ]                                                                         
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, you can use the [`$sampleRate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sampleRate/) operator:

```
// { x: 1 }
// { x: 2 }
// { x: 3 }
// { x: 4 }
// { x: 5 }
// { x: 6 }
db.collection.aggregate([ { $match: { $sampleRate: 0.33 } } ])
// { x: 3 }
// { x: 5 }
```

This matches a random selection of input documents (33%). The number of documents selected approximates the sample rate expressed as a percentage of the total number of documents.

Note that this is equivalent to adding a random number between 0 and 1 for each document and filtering them in if this random value is bellow 0.33. Such that you may get more or less documents in output, and running this several times won't necessarily give you the same output.